# Javascript to identify if a window is open

Tags: javascript

I want to identify if a window is open prior to opening the page.

i.e.

```
winObj = window.open("Test.aspx",WinName",...);
```

I have to find whether the Test.aspx page is open already before opening the same.

Please help!!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `winObj.closed` property:

```
if (!winObj && !winObj.closed) {
    ...
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_closed.asp for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting to know whether it is actually "Test.aspx" that is still open? Because the user could have changed urls?

You could always check to see if your window object has the location your trying to reload...I'm wondering whether you simply want to prevent "overwriting" the same page...So you could do this by checking the location (url) in the opened window

```
// at some point the window is open
winObj = window.open("Test.aspx"...);

// future event in original page
if (typeof(winObj) !== "undefined") {
   if (winObj.location) {
      if (winObj.location == "Test.aspx") {
        //alert("Test.aspx is already open in another window");
      };
   };
};
```